# jquery make single variables from returned array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, variables, return

Hello I have a function and I would like to make variables from returned array, is it possible?

```
var food,car=getItems();

function getItems(){
     var array=["pizza","audi"];
     return array;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to assign `pizza` to `food` and `audi` to `car`?

Comment: yes, exactly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap your variables in `[]` to use [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) (no jQuery needed):

```
var [food,car]=getItems();
```

```js
var [food,car]=getItems();

function getItems(){
     var array=["pizza","audi"];
     return array;
}

console.log(food,car)
```